# Tweepy error: attribute error

Tags: python, twitter, urllib, tweepy

The code was working fine but all of a sudden this error started to raise, though I did not change my codebase.

```
searched_tweets = ( status._json for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, count=300, since=from_date, until=to_date,
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/cursor.py", line 197, in next
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/cursor.py", line 108, in next
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 189, in execute
tweepy.error.TweepError:
      Failed to send request: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPMessage'
```

I had another python script which also used tweepy. But that also started throwing error:

```
stream.filter(track=keyword_list, stall_warnings=True)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPMessage'
```

I have no idea what is causing this error. I even tried reinstalling tweepy but no luck. Any help is highly appreciated!

Edit: I figured out that it's coming from tweepy's `binder.py`:
[image: TweepError]

Comment: Did you run any `tweepy` update recently? Although, I doubt if that would be the cause

Comment: No, I didn't do any update to tweepy. I'm having hard time to understand this error. There are no articles regarding this error too.

Comment: You could go to your `/site-packages/` directory and delete the pip folder as I feel there are some conflict in older files and the new ones. Then, you could install `pip` all over again.

Comment: you meant, tweepy files like `tweepy-3.5.0-py2.7.egg`,  `requests_oauthlib-0.5.0-py2.7.egg`,  `six.py`. my tweepy installation files are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by installing Anaconda3.4 and then,

> > pip3 install tweepy

I suppose that it was a dependency or an update issue.